# What is needed to make a wait statement within a process with a sensitivity list

Tags: vhdl

I would like to have a process in paralel with a process that receives filter (code bellow). This filter will change if I have 16 bits in data_to_memory signal then I will in the other process store this in a variable and perform some filter calculations. I think that my code is correct but still gives me the error: A wait statement is illegal for a process with a sensitivity list.
I have this two process in a file and my testbench in a different file.

```
process(bits_received)
begin

        if rising_edge(bits_received) then
    bits_data_rec(7 downto 0)<=data_in;
    filter<='0';
    wait until rising_edge(bits_received);
    data_to_memory<=bits_data_rec&data_in;
    filter<='1';
    wait for clock_period;
    filter<='0';
end if;
end process;
```

the process in my testbench:

```
file_open(file_pointer,"inputs.txt",READ_MODE);
file_open(file_RESULTS,"target.txt",WRITE_MODE);
reset<='1';
wait for clock_period/2;
reset<='0';
wait for clock_period/2;

    
    
      while not endfile(file_pointer) loop
      readline(file_pointer, line_num);
      read(line_num, data);
     
      data_in<=data(7 downto 0);
      bits_received<='1';
      wait for clock_period;
      bits_received<='0';
      data_in<=data(15 downto 8);
      bits_received<='1';
      wait for clock_period;
      bits_received<='0';
      wait for clock_period;
        
WRITE(v_OLINE,out_filter);
writeline(file_RESULTS, v_OLINE);
wait for clock_period;

        wait for clock_period;


end loop;
```

Is my testbench affecting the process(bits_received)?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. The idea is future readers can use questions and answers as a search resource for problem solving. You don't provide enough detail, instead seek a way to make a proposed fix work. A wait statement doesn't synthesize except waiting on clock events or until edges. Physical literals (`clock_period`, of type time) are ignored. A process can't contain both a wait statement and a process sensitivity list. Your process would be syntactically valid if the process sensitivity list were removed and `wait on bits_received;` were added as a last statement which is equivalent.

Comment: rising_edge should only be used with clock signals. If you need to detect a rising edge on a data/control signal, use a flip-flop and an edge detector.